# Merge values in a single List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a simple `List<string>` with colon delimited values.

Some values, however, may be the same before the colon, but different after. I need to merge these two values based on the last most value.

**Example**

```
name:john
surname:michael
gender:boy
name:pete
title:captain
```

would become

```
surname:michael
gender:boy
name:pete
title:captain
```

Comment: @SonerGönül that isnt what I'm looking to do :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list = list.GroupBy(s => s.Split(':')[0].ToLower())
           .Select(g => g.Last())
           .ToList();
```

Comment: This actually works exactly as I needed. Super simple too! Thanks :D

Comment: @Jamiec Try it out before stating a lie ;) GroupBy stores the keys as `Key` and you can enumerate over the values.

Comment: Works well. Better than mine :?

Answer (score 0):

In general: Use a Dictionary --> you're using a List AS a dictionary.

I prefer LazyDictionarys that you can update without checking key existance but for a standard .Net Dict in pseudocode

```
dict = new Dictionary()
for each item in your_LIST
{
    tmp = item.Split(':')
    if dict.ContainsKey(tmp[0]) 
    {
       dict[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]
    }
    else
    {
       dict.Add(tmp[0],tmp[1])
    }
}
```

ANd you have a dictionary,  which is what you want,  if you really want to then convet it back to a list then fine,  but really you probably want this to be a dictionary 'all the way down'

Answer (score 0):

It can be cone using linq

```
private string[] inputs = new string[]
{
    "name:john",
    "surname:michael",
    "gender:boy",
    "name:pete",
    "title:captain",
};

private string[] expected = new string[]
{
    "surname:michael",
    "gender:boy",
    "name:pete",
    "title:captain",
};


private static List<string> FilterList(IEnumerable<string> src) {
    return src.Select(s =>
    {
        var pieces = s.Split(':');
        return new {Name = pieces[0], Value = pieces[1]};
    }).GroupBy(m => m.Name)
      .Select(g => String.Format("{0}:{1}", g.Key, g.Last().Value)).ToList();;

}

[TestMethod]
public void TestFilter() {

    var actual = FilterList(inputs);

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);

}
```